# Package Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 25.4.0.2 supports: monoandroid70 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.0)

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I have Visual Studio 2017 Full Package.
I am using Xamarin for making android app but I have an error when I making blank page
[see photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRKwR.png)
What error is it?
How to solve it?
I want to run my android app with minSdk 23 (Android 6.0)

Comment: Hi. You need to describe the specific error you are experiencing with words, not with a picture, and make that the title of your question. Otherwise it's too generic to be useful.

Comment: I have changed it

Comment: try going through your packages via the nuget manager and update the ones you see in the errormessage

Comment: where can I find nuget manager?

Comment: What is your project target version? It seems that your target version is Android 6.0(API 23) but your nuget package version is Android 7.1(API 25), so change your target version to API 25m, delete bin and obj files and try again.